# Why the first column of a Microsoft excel 97-2003 worksheet reads the variable names as an observation in R?

Tags: r

The worksheet is a 97-2003 MS excel file.While reading it in R it reads the first column as an observation and not as variable name.What could be missing?

```
library(readxl)
Factor_Analysis <- read_excel("Factor Analysis.xls",col_names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the excel file has an empty row in the top? if so try using `skip = 1` as an argument, if it has more than that add as many as you need to remove to get the data to be the top row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding skip=1 worked as excel had 1 empty row at top.

```
Factor_Analysis <- read_excel("Factor Analysis.xls",col_names = TRUE,skip=1)
```